# How to avoid SSRF error on request.getRequestURI()

Tags: spring, request, checkmarx, ssrf

I have the following code

```
String decodedUri = URLDecoder.decode(request.getRequestURI(),
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

I also have a regex which validates the url

```
decodedUri.matches("^\\/[/.a-zA-Z0-9-?&=]+$")
```

Still checkmarx shows SSRF error

How to avoid this

Comment: I am also facing same issue , what solution u applied for this